# How to hook UrlRewriter into Camel app?

Tags: apache-camel

In my Camel app, I've implemented a url rewriter (see end of this page: http://camel.apache.org/urlrewrite.html)

Only one problem, my UrlRewriter is never called.

How do I hook this rewriter in?

PS I'm using the following Camel mvn dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf-transport</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-urlrewrite</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please include the code where you try to wire in and use the urlrewrite.

Comment: I just added this code:

Comment: package beans;

import org.apache.camel.Producer;
import org.apache.camel.component.http.UrlRewrite;

public class AliveUrlRewrite implements UrlRewrite {
    @Override
    public String rewrite(String url, String relativeUrl, Producer producer) {
        return url.replaceAll("yahoo", "google");
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code where you wire in your AliveUrlRewrite and the code where you try to activate it.

Comment: That's my question. I don't "activate" anything. I created a class that implements the UrlRewrite interface. Now how do I get that class to actually get called?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing magic here. You defined the class and implemented UrlRewriter, good. Now, a route must use it.

for example, from the doc :

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:{{port}}/myapp?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
    .to("jetty:http://localhost:{{port2}}/myapp2?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false&urlRewrite=#myRewrite");
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the class but now you define a bean in the context, after you can call rewriteurl with bean name.

```
    SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
    CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);

    try {
        registry.put("rewriterUrl", new RewriterUrl());
```

and in the route you can define

```
.to("jetty:https://login?urlRewrite=#rewriterUrl")
```

For me this work, I don't know if it is useful for you.
Bye